# How to validate 2 inputs in Powershell and only proceed when both inputs are validated

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

Trying to write a script in Powershell that needs to validate 2 User Inputs before applying policies to the correct entries. With the basic script I wrote, It Validates the 1st Entry which is the User ID in the Teams Tenant. Then Validates the 2nd entry which is the telephone number using the validate regex. The problem I am having is that the policies Do not get applied when the correct information is applied. It skips that part and states a Warning and asks to check another profile.

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

 do {
    try {
    # 1st User Entry to check UserID
    $upnentry = Read-Host 'Enter the User Principle Name'
    
    # Validate in Teams Tenant if this ID exists, If Not, 
    # prompt to enter a valid entry again

    $csu = Get-CsOnlineUser -Identity $upnentry -ErrorAction Stop
    $csu | Format-List IsSipEnabled, Displ*
    Write-Host 'User ID has been verified correctly!'

   # 2nd User Entry to check for valid Telephone Number 
   
    $phoneinputblock = {
    try
    {
     [validatescript({[regex]::Match($_,'^27\d{9}$').Length -eq  11})]
     $phoneUserInput = Read-Host "`nEnter Telephone Number"
     $phoneUserInput
     }
     catch{ Write-Warning "Incorrect Format for Telephone Number!"
     & $phoneinputBlock
      }
    }
   $phoneuserInput = & $phoneinputBlock
   Write-Host 'Telephone Number is in the correct format!'

   Set-CsPhoneNumberAssignment -Identity $user -PhoneNumber 
   $phonenumberinput -PhoneNumberType DirectRouting
   Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy -PolicyName VRP- International -Identity $upnentry
   Write-host "Policies applied successfully for : $upnentry"  - ForegroundColor Green
   }
   catch { Write-Warning "You've entered an invalid UserID: $upnentry"
   }
   } until($Host.UI.PromptForChoice('', 'Do you want to check another Users Profile?', 
   ('&Yes', '&No'), 0))
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not perform the two tests inside nested try--catch blocks like that, but instead use a boolean variable to keep track of the result from the first test and only if that is true proceed with the rest.

Something like this:

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

 do {
    $testID = $false
    try {
        # 1st User Entry to check UserID
        $upnentry = Read-Host 'Enter the User Principle Name'

        # Validate in Teams Tenant if this ID exists, If Not, 
        # prompt to enter a valid entry again

        $csu = Get-CsOnlineUser -Identity $upnentry -ErrorAction Stop
        $csu | Format-List IsSipEnabled, Displ*
        Write-Host 'User ID has been verified correctly!'
        $testID = $true
    }
    catch { Write-Warning "You've entered an invalid UserID: $upnentry"}

    if ($testID) {
        # 2nd User Entry to check for valid Telephone Number 
        while ($true) {
            $phoneUserInput = Read-Host "`r`nEnter Telephone Number"
            if ([regex]::Match($phoneUserInput,'^27\d{9}$').Length -eq 11) {
                Write-Host 'Telephone Number is in the correct format!'
                break  # exit the loop
            }
            # here we have a wrong phone number, so ask again
            Write-Host "`r`nThe Telephone Number is in the wrong format. Should start with 27 followed by nine digits" -ForegroundColor Red
            if ((Read-Host "Do you want to stop here (Yes/No) ?") -match '^Y') { # exit the script
                exit
            }
        }
        # here we know both entries are correct, so proceed setting the phone number
        try {
            Set-CsPhoneNumberAssignment -Identity $upnentry -PhoneNumber $phoneUserInput -PhoneNumberType DirectRouting -ErrorAction Stop
            Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy -PolicyName 'VRP- International' -Identity $upnentry -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-host "Policies applied successfully for: $upnentry"  - ForegroundColor Green
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning "Error setting the phone number: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
} until ($Host.UI.PromptForChoice('', 'Do you want to check another Users Profile?', ('&Yes', '&No'), 0))
```

Comment: Hi @Theo, Thank you kindly for responding. Your solution really helped me progress with my task which I was trying to get right for days....... It works to an extent however I just have one thing that needs to be fixed. If a wrong telephone number is entered - How can the script just re-prompt for another telephone number instead of 'promptforchoice' again and asking for UserID and Telephone number? Please see Picture posted. Thank you kindly.

Comment: @Dillon Should be doable, bit I'm on mobile now, so I will not be able to do that until tomorrow

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Hope to hear from you soon!

Comment: @Dillon Please see my edited answer. It now uses an endless loop asking for the phone number and when this does not match your regex, the user can either exit the script or enter a new (correct) telephone number

Comment: Thank you ever so much! :) It works perfectly as expected. It's exactly what I needed. I will tweak it a bit, however i could not have done it without your expertise.